# Foundation 3 - media queries and form bug

Tags: forms, zurb-foundation

i have a little problem with the foundation 3 framework and their form... When i use this meta-viewport: meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" and switching on tablets from landscape to portrait the body creates a kind of spacing to the right. Have anyone else this problem and can give me a hint, how to fix this?

Comment: The meta tag by itself is ok, search for a stylesheet that may cause the issue.

Comment: hmmm, the other stylesheets are all ok. The foundation frameworks seems to have a problem with this special meta-viewport and the included forms. I dont know why... Hope there is someone who have the same problem and may find a solution?